# How do I search a particular string out of file1, and update a csv file

Tags: python

I have two very large files:

```
File1 is formatted as such:
thisismy@email.com:20110708
thisisnotmy@email.com:20110908
thisisyour@email.com:20090807
...
```

File2 is a csv file that has the same email addresses in the row[0] field, and I need to put the date into the row[5] field.

I understand how to properly read & parse the csv, as well I comprehend how to read the File1 and cut it properly.

What I need assistance with is how to properly search the CSV file for ANY instances of the email address and update the csv with the corresponding date.

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Try the python CSV module: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Comment: How large is very large?  You should be able to do it just fine for a half-million records or more, just by using a plain old `dict` and csv reader

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check using module `re`::

```
import re
emails = re.findall(r'^(.*\@.*?):', open('filename.csv').read())
```

That will get you all the emails.

Comment: I may not have described what I am intending to do properly.  I am reading in the line and splitting out the email address just fine.  Then I need to search the CSV file for ANY instances for the email address and update the date field.  The problem is I am working with HUGE files, and looking for the best way to do this.

Comment: Can you load the file into the memory using a dictionary first? Then update the dictionary and reconstruct the CSV file?

Comment: What is the file size of the CSV? It would be better to import them into a SQL instead if you need such kind of query.

Comment: The CSV is about 150mb. (it is huge) and the file with email/date is about 8mb (also pretty big)

Comment: It would be more appropriate to use a database in this case. Try to load the file into [MySQL](http://support.modwest.com/content/6/253/en/how-do-i-import-delimited-data-into-mysql.html). It will be a lot faster and easier. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the data you have to replace has a fixed size, which seems to be the case in your example. You can use [seek()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek). While reading your file looking for your value, get the cursor position and write your replacement data from the desired position.

Cf: [Writing in file's actual position in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188214/writing-in-files-actual-position-in-python)

However, if you are dealing with extra huge files, using command line tools such as `sed` could save a lot of processing time.

Answer (score 0):

Below example tested on Python 2.7:

```
import csv

# 'b' flag for binary is necessary if on Windows otherwise crlf hilarity ensues
with open('/path/to/file1.txt','rb') as fin:
  csv_reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=":")
  # Header in line 1? Skip over. Otherwise no need for next line.
  csv_reader.next() 
  # populate dict with email address as key and date as value
  # dictionary comprehensions supported in 2.7+
  # on a lower version? use: d = dict((line[0],line[1]) for line in csv_reader)
  email_address_dict = {line[0]: line[1] for line in csv_reader}

# there are ways to modify a file in-place
# but it's easier to write to a new file 
with open('/path/to/file2.txt','rb') as fin, \
     open('/path/to/file3.txt','wb') as fou:
  csv_reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=":")
  csv_writer = csv.writer(fou, delimiter=":")
  # Header in line 1? Skip over. Otherwise no need for next line.
  csv_writer.writerow( csv_reader.next() ) 
  for line in csv_reader:
    # construct new line 
    # looking up date value in just-created dict
    # the new date value is inserted position 5 (zero-based)
    newline = line[0:5]
    newline.append(email_address_dict[line[0]])
    newline.extend(line[6:])
    csv_writer.writerow(newline)
```